# Computer turns off and on after start ..then goes dead

Tags: power-supply, power

I built a new PC from the following components:
- CPU: Intel Core i7 950
- MB: Gigabyte X58A-UD3R
- RAM: 2x2gb i7 Corsair memory
- VGA: Zotac AMP2 GTX260
- HDD: 1 GreenSATA HDD (Western Digital 500gb RE2)

When I turn it on, it goes for a few seconds, fans at maximum speed, then turns off.
The again, it starts by itself.. and goes with fans on max speed, nothing happens.

First I suspected my PSU. It's a Chieftec 450AA PSU.
After I borrowed a Chieftec 550AA PSU, I tried to start with that.

Exact same story.
Any idea ? Do I need a bigger PSU?

Reason why its not localized. I never seen this turn on, off, on.
If you give answer for that, it would already help people like me, with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your RAM sticks are faulty. You should try unplugging them and plugging them back.

Also, I suggest you check every cable connection between the motherboard and the components.

EDIT: Does your BIOS make any beeping noise? It may be notifying you of a problem.
Here are databases for AMI Bios, Award and Phoenix

- http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/tp/ami-beep-codes.htm
- http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/tp/award-beep-codes.htm
- http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/tp/phoenix-beep-codes.htm

Comment: I'll try it with other sticks, lucky that my friend got DDR3 too. About the cables.. they are connected.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't express myself correctly. By checking the cables, I suggest you unplug and plug them back again firmly.

Comment: Oh the beep is a good idea. Completely forgot about the PC speakers. :)

Comment: They were installed in a wrong order. A guy helped me out, the manual was wrong.. just a little bit lol. Thanks for the idea and sorry for the late accept!

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it!